# Arrange R plots in a custom layout

Tags: r

I would like to combine five plots in R as the following structure:

[image]

I can use par(mfrow=c(2,3)),however, in that case, the bottom 2 plots (in row 2) are left aligned. How to move these in center? Or if I use layout and matrix, what should be the appropriate dimension for that? It is too mention that all the plots have same width.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `layout()`. For this you need to create a plot layout by creating a matrix containing the indices of the plots in the positions you want them. To achieve the effect you want, you're going to need to allocate more columns than you have plots to allow for the offset. In the example I show below, I assume plots take up two column each and that therefore the offset for the bottom row is half a plot in width:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,
                0,4,4,5,5,0), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

This gives

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    2    2    3    3
[2,]    0    4    4    5    5    0
```

The `0`s mean that no plot will be drawn in that location.

With that `mat` in place, you pass it to `layout()`, do your plotting and then reset using `layout(1)`. Here is an example to illustrate

```
layout(mat)
for (i in seq_len(5)) {
    plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50),
         main = bquote(Plot ~ .(i)))
}
layout(1)
```

which produces:

[image]

You'll have to play with margins etc if you want there to be less white space, but at least this solves the proximal problem. of getting the layout you wanted.